# C# Count Rows from MySQL and display to datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I'm using DataGridView to display some data from MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM user where 'roles' = @roles
```

It is easy to display all data from database, but how can I give row count based on the rows I found ?

Example :
found **3 user** from database.

how can I give a row count **ID (1,2,3)** for each rows

[image]

some code

```
private void add(int id,String name)
{
  dataGridViewTable.Rows.Add(id,name);
}

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  int id = 0;
  add(id + 1, row[1].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Not clear what are you asking, if you have 10 rows you need to get data related to that 10 rows only?

Comment: what I'm trying to say is , if 10 rows found from database 
I want to display  them with  ID 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in datagirdview instead of their primary key ID from database

Comment: i want to change row[0].ToString()  // ID into 1, 2,3, 4,5

Comment: Still not clear what should be the output, so from your grid you need to get all the row[0]  to comma separated string

Comment: i edited the question again , is it better to understand now ?

Comment: So you rows should be 1,2,3 ? in that case declare int id = 0; before loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a debugging issue. Please learn to use the debugger as it might come in handy in the future.

The problem is the variable "id" is being initialized and set to zero with each loop. Pull the outside the loop and increment as needed.

This code should solve your immediate problem.

```
int id = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  add(id++, row[1].ToString());
}
```

Comment: That is what I told :P